# Why I am not able to apply border in the below code

Tags: html, css

**In the below code I am not able to apply the border**
can anybody indentify the problem

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
       <head>
           <title> My first Navigation Page</title>
```

In the CSS code I ave applied the margin but it cannot be applied to the nav tag

```
              <style type="text/CSS">
                  #margin
                  {
                     margin-top: 20px;
                     border: 1px;
                     padding: 2px; 
                     color:green;
                  }
                  </style>
                  </head>


                  <body>
                     <nav id="margin">
                               <a href="#" >html</a>
                               <a href="#">CSS</a>
                               <a href="#">Java Script</a>
                     </nav>
                     </body>
                     </html>
```

Comment: you need to specify a border color

Comment: @DanielA.White border color is not needed (it will default to color). border-style is the one missing here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your border has no `color`, so it is not noticeable.

If you use `border: 1px solid green` instead of `border 1px` you will see it appear:

```css
#margin {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav id="margin">
    <a href="#">html</a>
    <a href="#">CSS</a>
    <a href="#">Java Script</a>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

specify a border type and color

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
       <head>
           <title> My first Navigation Page</title>
         <style type="text/CSS">
                  #margin
                  {
                     margin-top: 20px;
                     border: 1px solid green;
                     padding: 2px; 
                     color:green;
                  }
                  </style>
                  </head>


                  <body>
                     <nav id="margin">
                               <a href="#" >html</a>
                               <a href="#">CSS</a>
                               <a href="#">Java Script</a>
                     </nav>
                     </body>
                     </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When adding borders you need to specify a border-width, border-color and border-style.

To shorthand this you do:

```
#margin {
   border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

That will make it a 1px width border, with a solid style and coloured black.

There are other options for the style of the border where you can replace `solid` with `dashed`, `dotted` and a few more I believe.

Things like this are so common with learning css that it's best to Google something such as 'how to add a border in css' then click on a css tricks, w3 schools or Mozilla developer network link, they explain fully what properties can be used.